# Communication between two subnets (home)

Tags: networking, routing

I previously asked this on `Network Engineering` but they kindly reminded me that this site is only for "professional" hardware. I hope that I'm at the right place now.

#### The Question:

So I'm new to this and I don't even know if this is the right forum so please redirect me if not.

I have a router `192.168.2.1` plugged into a LAN port of `192.168.3.1` (got swapped around because I thought the device might be faulty) and want to enable communication between those two subnets.

If I'm connected to the `2.1` router (which is plugged into `3.1`), I can ping it without any problems. The other way around it doesn't work.

So I thought I might need to set-up a route so `3.1` knows how to reach `2.1` and that's what I did.

The route:

- Route Name: `test`
- Destination LAN IP: `192.168.2.0`
- Subnet Mask: `255.255.255.0`
- Gateway: `192.168.2.1` (unsure about this one)
- Interface: `LAN`

But it tells me that this route is invalid.

Killed a few hours researching but everyone seems to be using some more advanced routers with terminal interfaces or their setup is too advanced/distant from mine so often I am unable to follow.

The router is: `Linksys E2500` (something a had laying around)

### Network schema:

[image]

I've now set up a route inside `3.1` looking like this:

- Destination LAN IP: `192.168.3.0`
- Subnet Mask: `255.255.255.0`
- Gateway: `192.168.3.5`

Which is not working. I've also noticed, that I cannot ping `192.168.3.5` from inside the `3.0` network, but I can whilst connected to the `2.0` one

Comment: Please draw a small scheme of your networks. Include all its nodes (PCs, routers, switches, APs, smartphones, network printers, TVs, etc... - everything) and show network settings for each interface (each cable between 2 devices must match 2 separate network settings of 2 interfaces of 2 devices connected by this cable). Show the connection to Internet (a socket from ISP) and specify its settings. Then tell what nodes must have the possibility for to communicate between. PS. Router between two networks must act as a bridge, not as router (NAT must be disabled) in general.

Comment: @Akina So I added a simple drawing but left out the endpoints as I don't think it's important.(?) And you say I have to put the router in bridge mode, but I actually want the network to be separated. So Each router runs its own DHCP and so on.

Comment: *(each cable between 2 devices must match 2 separate network settings of 2 interfaces of 2 devices connected by this cable)* Too low addresses, no masks/gateways. Square = switch? if so skip it.

Comment: Do you need two separate subnets?  If not, just assign the second router a static IP on subnet `192.168.2.0/24`.  If so, simply allow each router's subnet through the other's firewall and assign each router a static IP on the other's subnet, ensuring each subnet is compatible with the other (i.e. `192.168.2.0/26` and `192.168.2.64/26` or `192.168.2.0/25` and `192.168.2.128/25`, etc.).  See [Subnet Mask Cheat Sheet](https://www.aelius.com/njh/subnet_sheet.html)

Comment: Okay @Akina I don't think I know what you mean. There is a cable from `192.168.3.1` into the WAN port of `192.168.2.1`. I set the IP of `2.1` inside the interface and did not assign anything inside `3.1` at all. I really don't know what you mean by "second network settings" (I know what interfaces are but not how to set them up... kind of lost right here). Thanks in advance. @JW0914 Yes I know but I'd like to have it configured in this way.

Comment: @Akina Where would I find how the two interfaces on the two devices are configured? Like I said I just set the IP inside the `2.1` router's admin interface

Comment: *into the WAN port of 192.168.2.1* This node has WAN interface. So it has LAN interface at least. Each interface has its own unique IP address accompanied with subnet mask and maybe accompanied with default gateway address. I.e. you must give at least 2 IP/mask pairs and at least 1 gateway address per node. But you give us one IP only... *Where would I find how the two interfaces on the two devices are configured?* Look at device settings (maybe it have some web-interface?).

Comment: Ah, I may be onto something here. I just looked at the DHCP table and I found my routers MAC address. It's IP is currently `192.168.3.102` I hope you mean this ^^

Comment: Ohh so would that be the gateway?! ahh! And of course, I would need to set it up to be static

Comment: So the `2.0` router now has the fix-IP: `192.168.3.5` but I cannot ping it inside the `3.0` network. (The route I setup is also not working... this is kinda frustrating :( )

Comment: @Akina Updated the drawing. Hope it helps